# How to hide texblock if the text string value is equal to zero?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I’d like to have the texblock is not visible if the value that generated dynamically is equal to zero. I think it can be done solely in XAML using DataTrigger. I am wondering if someone can help to find the proper solution for this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to hide the textbox based on the value of that same textbox you could use something like the code below.

```
<TextBox Text="0">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Path=Text}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

You can add in a binding if you wanted. Also if you need to check the value of a different textbox to determine if this one should be shown you can alter the binding on the DataTrigger.